# couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available

Tags: postfix, authentication, email-server, imap, cyrus

I'm trying to use cyrus murder, I've been fixing some bugs but now I found this when trying to access from thunderbird:

*The current operation on 'Inbox' did not succeed. The mail server for account peter@ejemplo.org responded: Server(s) unavailable to complete operation.*

I have one backend and one frontend that is also a mupdate.

Looking at the logs (/var/log/maillog), in the frontend server see the following error:

*imap[2099]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available*

**This is the full log in frontend server (/var/log/maillog):**

```
Aug 27 14:55:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2098]: login: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org [169.254.220.13] murder PLAIN User logged in
Aug 27 14:55:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2098]: login: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org [169.254.220.13] murder PLAIN User logged in
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2101]: Thread timed out waiting for listener_lock
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2101]: Worker thread finished, for a total of 4 (4 spare)
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2101]: Thread timed out waiting for listener_lock
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2101]: Worker thread finished, for a total of 3 (3 spare)
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2101]: Thread timed out waiting for listener_lock
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2101]: Worker thread finished, for a total of 2 (2 spare)
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2098]: Thread timed out waiting for listener_lock
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2098]: Worker thread finished, for a total of 4 (4 spare)
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2098]: Thread timed out waiting for listener_lock
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2098]: Worker thread finished, for a total of 3 (3 spare)
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2098]: Thread timed out waiting for listener_lock
Aug 27 14:56:26 frontendlinux mupdate[2098]: Worker thread finished, for a total of 2 (2 spare)
Aug 27 14:59:13 frontendlinux imap[2099]: accepted connection
Aug 27 14:59:13 frontendlinux master[2198]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/proxyd
Aug 27 14:59:13 frontendlinux imap[2198]: executed
Aug 27 14:59:34 frontendlinux imap[2099]: login: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org [169.254.220.13] peter plain User logged in
Aug 27 14:59:34 frontendlinux imap[2099]: created decompress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 14:59:34 frontendlinux imap[2099]: created compress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 14:59:34 frontendlinux imap[2099]: client id: "name" "Thunderbird" "version" "17.0.8"
Aug 27 14:59:34 frontendlinux imap[2099]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available
Aug 27 14:59:34 frontendlinux imap[2099]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available
Aug 27 14:59:34 frontendlinux imap[2099]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available
Aug 27 14:59:34 frontendlinux imap[2099]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available
Aug 27 14:59:35 frontendlinux imap[2099]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available
Aug 27 15:08:47 frontendlinux imap[2116]: accepted connection
Aug 27 15:08:47 frontendlinux master[2258]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/proxyd
Aug 27 15:08:47 frontendlinux imap[2258]: executed
Aug 27 15:08:47 frontendlinux imap[2116]: login: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org [169.254.220.13] peter plain User logged in
Aug 27 15:08:47 frontendlinux imap[2116]: created decompress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 15:08:47 frontendlinux imap[2116]: created compress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 15:08:47 frontendlinux imap[2116]: client id: "name" "Thunderbird" "version" "17.0.8"
Aug 27 15:08:47 frontendlinux imap[2116]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available
Aug 27 15:18:48 frontendlinux imap[2119]: accepted connection
Aug 27 15:18:48 frontendlinux master[2268]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/proxyd
Aug 27 15:18:48 frontendlinux imap[2268]: executed
Aug 27 15:18:48 frontendlinux imap[2119]: login: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org [169.254.220.13] peter plain User logged in
Aug 27 15:18:48 frontendlinux imap[2119]: created decompress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 15:18:48 frontendlinux imap[2119]: created compress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 15:18:48 frontendlinux imap[2119]: client id: "name" "Thunderbird" "version" "17.0.8"
Aug 27 15:18:48 frontendlinux imap[2119]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available
Aug 27 15:25:25 frontendlinux master[2270]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/ctl_cyrusdb
Aug 27 15:25:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2270]: checkpointing cyrus databases
Aug 27 15:25:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2270]: archiving log file: /var/lib/imap/db/log.0000000001
Aug 27 15:25:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2270]: archiving log file: /var/lib/imap/db/log.0000000001
Aug 27 15:25:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2270]: archiving log file: /var/lib/imap/db/log.0000000001
Aug 27 15:25:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2270]: archiving database file: /var/lib/imap/annotations.db
Aug 27 15:25:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2270]: archiving database file: /var/lib/imap/mailboxes.db
Aug 27 15:25:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2270]: archiving log file: /var/lib/imap/db/log.0000000001
Aug 27 15:25:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2270]: done checkpointing cyrus databases
Aug 27 15:25:25 frontendlinux master[2077]: process 2270 exited, status 0
Aug 27 15:28:17 frontendlinux imap[2118]: accepted connection
Aug 27 15:28:17 frontendlinux imap[2118]: login: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org [169.254.220.13] peter plain User logged in
Aug 27 15:28:17 frontendlinux imap[2118]: created decompress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 15:28:17 frontendlinux imap[2118]: created compress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 15:28:17 frontendlinux imap[2118]: client id: "name" "Thunderbird" "version" "17.0.8"
Aug 27 15:28:17 frontendlinux imap[2118]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available
Aug 27 15:29:59 frontendlinux master[2077]: process 2099 exited, status 0
Aug 27 15:29:59 frontendlinux master[2282]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/proxyd
Aug 27 15:29:59 frontendlinux imap[2282]: executed
Aug 27 15:38:03 frontendlinux imap[2120]: accepted connection
Aug 27 15:38:03 frontendlinux imap[2120]: login: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org [169.254.220.13] peter plain User logged in
Aug 27 15:38:03 frontendlinux imap[2120]: created decompress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 15:38:03 frontendlinux imap[2120]: created compress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 15:38:03 frontendlinux imap[2120]: client id: "name" "Thunderbird" "version" "17.0.8"
Aug 27 15:38:03 frontendlinux imap[2120]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available
Aug 27 15:38:38 frontendlinux imap[2120]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available
Aug 27 15:39:46 frontendlinux master[2077]: process 2116 exited, status 0
Aug 27 15:39:46 frontendlinux master[2296]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/proxyd
Aug 27 15:39:46 frontendlinux imap[2296]: executed
Aug 27 15:48:02 frontendlinux imap[2198]: accepted connection
Aug 27 15:48:02 frontendlinux imap[2198]: login: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org [169.254.220.13] peter plain User logged in
Aug 27 15:48:02 frontendlinux imap[2198]: created decompress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 15:48:02 frontendlinux imap[2198]: created compress buffer of 4102 bytes
Aug 27 15:48:02 frontendlinux imap[2198]: client id: "name" "Thunderbird" "version" "17.0.8"
Aug 27 15:48:02 frontendlinux imap[2198]: couldn't authenticate to backend server: no mechanism available
Aug 27 15:49:23 frontendlinux master[2077]: process 2119 exited, status 0
Aug 27 15:49:23 frontendlinux master[2312]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/proxyd
Aug 27 15:49:23 frontendlinux imap[2312]: executed
Aug 27 15:55:25 frontendlinux master[2314]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/ctl_cyrusdb
Aug 27 15:55:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2314]: checkpointing cyrus databases
Aug 27 15:55:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2314]: archiving log file: /var/lib/imap/db/log.0000000001
Aug 27 15:55:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2314]: archiving log file: /var/lib/imap/db/log.0000000001
Aug 27 15:55:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2314]: archiving log file: /var/lib/imap/db/log.0000000001
Aug 27 15:55:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2314]: archiving database file: /var/lib/imap/annotations.db
Aug 27 15:55:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2314]: archiving database file: /var/lib/imap/mailboxes.db
Aug 27 15:55:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2314]: archiving log file: /var/lib/imap/db/log.0000000001
Aug 27 15:55:25 frontendlinux ctl_cyrusdb[2314]: done checkpointing cyrus databases
```

I have the following settings:

======================= **Configuration of backend** =======================

Server Name: backend.ejemplo.org

Operating System: Centos 6.0 (Final)

Server SMTP: Postfix 2.6.6

Server IMAP: Cyrus IMAP Murder v2.3.16-Fedora-RPM-2.3.16-6.el6_2.5 server ready

**postconf -n:**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
local_destination_recipient_limit = 300
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = ejemplo.org
myhostname = backend.ejemplo.org
mynetworks_style = host
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = no #majito toco
smtpd_banner = $myhostname
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,                               
permit_mynetworks,                         
permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

**/etc/imapd.conf:**

```
partition-default: /var/spool/imap
mupdate_server: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org
mupdate_port: 3905
mupdate_username: murder
mupdate_authname: murder
mupdate_password: foo
#admins: cyrus
proxyservers: murder
configdirectory: /var/lib/imap
sievedir: /var/lib/imap/sieve
sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail
hashimapspool: true
sasl_pwcheck_method: saslauthd
sasl_mech_list: PLAIN
# qosmarking: af13
defaultdomain: ejemplo.org
servername: backend.ejemplo.org
allowanonymouslogin:    no
allowplaintext:         yes
#autocreatequota:                -1
#createonpost:                   yes
#autocreateinboxfolders:         spam
#autosubscribeinboxfolders:      spam

admins: cyrus murder
unixhierarchysep: 1
```

**/etc/cyrus.conf:**

```
partition-default: /var/spool/imap
mupdate_server: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org
mupdate_port: 3905
mupdate_username: murder
mupdate_authname: murder
mupdate_password: foo
proxyservers: murder
configdirectory: /var/lib/imap
sievedir: /var/lib/imap/sieve
sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail
hashimapspool: true
sasl_pwcheck_method: saslauthd
sasl_mech_list: PLAIN
defaultdomain: ejemplo.org
servername: backend.ejemplo.org
allowanonymouslogin:    no
allowplaintext:         yes
admins: cyrus murder
unixhierarchysep: 1
```

**/etc/cyrus.conf:**

```
START {
  recover       cmd="ctl_cyrusdb -r"
  idled         cmd="idled"
}

# UNIX sockets start with a slash and are put into /var/lib/imap/sockets
SERVICES {
  imap          cmd="imapd" listen="imap" prefork=5
  pop3          cmd="pop3d" listen="pop3" prefork=3
  sieve         cmd="timsieved" listen="sieve" prefork=0
  lmtpunix      cmd="lmtpd" listen="/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp" prefork=1
}

EVENTS {
  checkpoint    cmd="ctl_cyrusdb -c" period=30
  delprune      cmd="cyr_expire -E 3" at=0400
  tlsprune      cmd="tls_prune" at=0400
}
```

**/etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf:**

pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login

======================= **Configuration of frontend** =======================

Server Name: frontendlinux.ejemplo.org

Operating System: Centos 6.0 (Final)

Server SMTP: Postfix 2.6.6

Server IMAP: Cyrus IMAP Murder v2.3.16-Fedora-RPM-2.3.16-6.el6_2.5 server ready

**postconf -n:**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
local_destination_recipient_limit = 300
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = ejemplo.org
myhostname = frontendlinux.ejemplo.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.100.0/24, 169.254.220.0/24
mynetworks_style = host
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_banner = $myhostname
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,                                  permit_mynetworks,                                  reject_unauth_destination,                                  reject_invalid_hostname,                                  reject_non_fqdn_hostname,                                  reject_non_fqdn_sender,                                  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,                                  reject_unknown_sender_domain,                                  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,                                  reject_unauth_pipelining,                                  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,                                  reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,                                  reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org,                                  reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,                                  permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_tls_cert_file = none
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

**/etc/imapd.conf:**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
local_destination_recipient_limit = 300
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = ejemplo.org
myhostname = frontendlinux.ejemplo.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.100.0/24, 169.254.220.0/24
mynetworks_style = host
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_banner = $myhostname
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
                permit_sasl_authenticated,                                  
                permit_mynetworks,                                  
                reject_unauth_destination, 
                reject_invalid_hostname,                                  
                reject_non_fqdn_hostname,                                  
                reject_non_fqdn_sender,                                  
                reject_non_fqdn_recipient,                                  
                reject_unknown_sender_domain,                                  
                reject_unknown_recipient_domain,                                  
                reject_unauth_pipelining,                                  
                reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,                                  
                reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,                                  
                reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org,                                  
                reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,                                  
                permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_tls_cert_file = none
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

**/etc/cyrus.conf**

```
START {
  recover       cmd="ctl_cyrusdb -r"
  idled         cmd="idled"
}

SERVICES {
  mupdate       cmd="/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/mupdate -m" listen=3905 prefork=1
  imap          cmd="proxyd" listen="imap" prefork=5
  sieve         cmd="timsieved" listen="sieve" prefork=0
   lmtp         cmd="lmtpproxyd" listen="lmtp" prefork=1 maxchild=20
}

EVENTS {
  checkpoint    cmd="ctl_cyrusdb -c" period=30
  delprune      cmd="cyr_expire -E 3" at=0400
  tlsprune      cmd="tls_prune" at=0400
}
```

**/etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf**

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`yum install cyrus-sasl-plain`

maybe solves your problem.

Comment: Please try to elaborate a bit, e.g. why is that specific package needed?

Comment: I could reach the expected solution!.
I made many modifications and can not remember which of all was the solution.
Then I will write a post explaining and share it.
Currently I have cyrus murder sso running windows server 2003 with mit kerberos